# Samsung Galaxy S2 - Screen Lock Options Disabled

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, lock-screens, 4.3-jelly-bean

Following the recent upgrade to Jelly Bean on my Samsung Galaxy S2, I have enabled the lock screen with password but when I want to change the other options to like Swipe, Motion, face Unlock Pattern, PIN and None which they are disabled.

Other than the option "password (High Security)" option rest of the above mentioned are disabled. Don't know how to disable the screen lock password.

I have gone through various website & forum and YouTube videos none explains this issue.

How can I remove the screen lock?

Comment: Do you have a "device administrator" set for this phone, or Exchange sync or a VPN set up?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the "With swipe lock" checkbox and see if that enables it.

I have no idea what "With swipe lock" does, other than enabling the "Lock screen options". You can enable it, change the options, and disable it, and the options will stay changed. *shrug*

No, it doesn't make any sense to me, either.